# firebird c# insert error -206 Column unknown

Tags: c#, .net, insert, firebird2.5

I'm just starting with Firebird and C#, and I have a problem:

I want to insert into my Firebird database with:

```
FbCommand fbcon = new FbCommand("INSERT INTO REZEPTE(NAME) VALUES (@NAME)", con);
fbcon.Parameters.AddWithValue("NAME", textBox1.Text);          
fbcon.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But I get an error:

> SQL error code = -206 Column unknown

But still the column is saved in the database. If I add '' around the text in the text box the error does not show and the '' are also saved in the database.

The column in my database is a `VarChar`.

Comment: Try AddWithValue("@NAME"....  The param is looking for what to add to FbCommand.

Comment: Still the same problem :(

Answer (score -2):

I'm sorry the Error was later in my Code:

```
    FbCommand readCommand = 
    new FbCommand("Select ID From rezepte where name = '"+textBox1.Text+"'", con);
    FbDataReader myreader=  readCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

I forgot the ' around the select at my textbox...

Comment: SQL Injection !

Comment: You should really use parameters there (just like in the code you use in your question!) As it stands your code contains a big (and avoidable) security risk.

Comment: I'm just getting started and its hard enough to get the code running :) But ur right if i do it i should do it right. Thanks